# Activation event getting triggered by PasteSpecial operation

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, paste, worksheet-function

While programming a module in VBA that operates on copy-pasting a range based on formulae on a sheet, the currently activated sheet's `Worksheet_Activate` event is triggered.

I know that I can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to disable the trigger, however, I would like to understand why the `PasteSpecial` operation for a `Range` object triggers the `Worksheet_Activate` method, as I cannot find any mention of the same on the Range.PasteSpecial [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial), or what [actions trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.activate%28even%29) the `Worksheet_Activate` event.

For a reproducible example, please create a workbook with two sheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, and insert code in `Sheet1` as so:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    MsgBox "Sheet 1 has been activated."

End Sub
```

Add a separate module with code as so:

```
Public Sub copy_and_paste_in_sheet2()

    Set Rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")
    Rng1.Copy

    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B12")
    rng2.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

**While `Sheet1` is activated**, run the `copy_and_paste_in_sheet2` macro, and it will be evident that the `Worksheet_Activate` event for `Sheet1` is triggered despite no apparent code in the second module explicitly doing so.

I would expect that notwithstanding any use of `Select` operations that require the `Activate` command to work, the `PasteSpecial` operation should not ideally trigger the `Worksheet_Activate` event. Could you please direct me to the relevant documentation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be one of the odd things you may have when dealing with Excel: `PasteSpecial` quickly "activates" the sheet you are pasting to. You can see the screen flicker (at least I can, using a VM that is rather slow when it comes to screen updating). Also, if you put similar event code to sheet2, you will see that it is triggered also.

The strange thing is that in the triggered sheet you see still sheet1 as `ActiveSheet`. So the following code (as event routine of Sheet2) will print *"activate 2 Sheet1"*

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     Debug.Print "activate 2 " & ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

I doubt that you will find any documentation for that behaviour. And your best bet is to accept this and (as you already wrote) use `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: I was afraid of this situation. `ActiveSheet.Name` for me in the the second module does show `Sheet1` to be active, using `MsgBox "Sheet 2 was activated, and ActiveSheet.Name gives: " & ActiveSheet.Name` in the module code. Thank you, though!